# Magento 2.3: I am trying to add text into the small cart, but it's not working

Tags: module, cart, magento2.3, extensions

I want to add text into the cart showed in the picture, but unfortunately my code does not work. 
[image]

This is my file structure:

[image]

Code in ButtonGet.php:

```
<?php
namespace MassiveArt\ShoppingCart\Block;
class ButtonGet extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

}
```

Code in get_cart_index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <referenceContainer name="minicart.addons">
                <block class="MassiveArt\ShoppingCart\Block\ButtonGet" after="-" name="custom_button" template="MassiveArt_ShoppingCart::button_getcart.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Code in button_getcart.phtml:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

The Rest of my Module is working proberly, but this Text not. Can you help me?

Comment: which position you want to show text ??

Comment: before the "view and edit cart" link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create File In `MassiveArt/ShoppingCart/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="minicart.addons">
            <block class="MassiveArt\ShoppingCart\Block\ButtonGet" name="minicart.movetoquote" template="MassiveArt_ShoppingCart::button_getcart.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Create phtml File In `MassiveArt/ShoppingCart/view/frontend/templates/button_getcart.phtml`

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Comment: I did this, but it is not working.

Comment: create default.xml file as per my answer

Comment: why cant I name it get_cart_index.xml? Because with the name default.xml it is working. I just not understand why? But thanks a lot.

Comment: default.xml is always excute so